# insert script with serials in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is how I do this in sql server.

```
insert into users(name) values('jhon');
set @id = @@identity; -- last serial

insert into usersroles(@id, 1)
insert into usersroles(@id, 2)
insert into usersroles(@id, 3)
```

How can I do the same in postgres (withouth creating a function)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL NOT NULL, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE userroles (user_id INT NOT NULL, role_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    users (name)
VALUES  ('John');

INSERT
INTO    userroles (user_id, role_id)
VALUES  (CURRVAL('users_id_seq'), 1),
        (CURRVAL('users_id_seq'), 2),
        (CURRVAL('users_id_seq'), 3);
```

Comment: cool, but is there any other way like using declare or that's only inside plpgsql functions ?

Comment: @Omu: `DECLARE` is only within `PL/PGSQL`. You can use unholy magic with `custom_variable_classes` to set session variables, but I wouldn't recommend this. Actually, what's bad in the `CURRVAL` solution?

Comment: @Quassnoi nothing, it's just my first day with postgres and I'm used with the sql server stuff

Comment: Is `CURRVAL` concurrency safe?  Meaning, if another query called `NEXTVAL('users_id_seq')` between the INSERTS --wouldn't CURRVAL reflect the latest value and not the intended one?

Comment: @OMG Ponies it looks like so http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-sequence.html "Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence in the current session"

Comment: @Omu: That minimizes the window of opportunity, but it doesn't specify if the transaction is respected.

Comment: @OMGPonies: `CURRVAL` is implemented as a session variable. The queries called from another sessions do not affect `CURRVAL`. You have full control of the queries within your own session. This means that if you don't increment the sequence within your session, `CURRVAL` persists, even if another query in another session messes with the sequence. It's similar to `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can use the keyword DEFAULT to specify the default value for the column. And the Postgres extension RETURNING to return the id that was just inserted.

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (default, 'Bob') RETURNING id;
```

Comment: how do you insert the returned value into another table without storing it into a variable first?

Comment: You don't. The point of using returning is to stuff it in a variable. If you don't want to use variables then you'll need to use currval()